# How do I animate my Navigation Button to perform the proper animation assigned to it using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

So here's what I have and I can figure out why my burger div (navigation button on mobile) won't animate to shape a X can anyone explain what I'm missing or doing wrong?
Ive tried changing the class name using toggle through javaScript but it doesn't animate the lines 45 degrees and Im unsure why that is?
I would like to know what I can do in terms of changing the burger (nav button) to form a X and hide the center line by fading it out using a javaScript

This also my first time using stack overflow in terms of asking a question so please go easy on me.

```js
const navSlide = () => {
    const burger = document.querySelector('.burger');
    const nav = document.querySelector('.nav-items');
    const navItems = document.querySelectorAll('.nav-items li');

    burger.addEventListener('click', () => {
        //NAV Toggle
        nav.classList.toggle('nav-active');

        //Items Animated
        navItems.forEach((item, index) => {
            if (item.style.animation) {
                item.style.animation = '';
            } else {
                item.style.animation = `navItemFade 0.5s ease forwards ${index / 7 + .3}s`;
            }
        });
        //Burger Animation
        burger.classList.toggle('tip');

    });
}

navSlide();
```

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

html {
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: rgb(245, 245, 245);
    transition: .3s;
}

/* NAV */
nav {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    min-height: 11vh;
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    background-color: rgb(255, 145, 0);
}

.logo {
    margin-left: 3rem;
}

.logo>a>h1 {
    color: rgb(245, 245, 245);
    letter-spacing: 3px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 32px;
}

.nav-items {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin-right: 25rem;
}

.nav-items>li {
    padding: 1.5rem;
}

.nav-items>li>a {
    font-size: 16px;
}

.nav-items>li>a:hover {
    color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
}

.nav-icons {
    display: flex;
    margin-right: 2rem;
}

.nav-fas {
    margin: 1rem;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.burger {
    display: none;
    margin-left: 1rem;
}

.burger>div {
    width: 25px;
    height: 3px;
    background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    margin: 5px;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

/* NAV MOBILE */

@media screen and (max-width:1240px) {
    .nav-items {
        margin-right: 10px;
        transition: .3s;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width:860px) {
    body {
        overflow-x: hidden;
    }

    .nav-items {
        width: 100%;
        max-width: 300px;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        justify-content: space-evenly;
        position: absolute;
        height: 90vh;
        top: 14vh;
        background-color: rgb(255, 145, 0);
        transform: translateX(-100%);
        transition: transform 0.5s ease-in;
    }

    .nav-items li {
        opacity: 0;
    }

    .burger {
        display: block;
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    #fas1,
    #fas2 {
        display: none;
    }
}

.nav-active {
    transform: translateX(0%);
}

@keyframes navItemFade {
    from {
        opacity: 0;
        transform: translateX(50px);
    }

    to {
        opacity: 1;
        transform: translateX(0px);
    }
}

.tip .line1 {
    transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-5px, 6px);
}

.tip .line2 {
    opacity: 0;
}

.tip .line3 {
    transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-5px, -6px);
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>E-Store</title>
</head>

<body>
    <header>
        <nav>
            <div class="burger">
                <div clsss="line1"></div>
                <div clsss="line2"></div>
                <div clsss="line3"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="logo">
                <a href="index.html">
                    <h1>logo</h1>
                </a>
            </div>
            <ul class="nav-items">
                <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#collection">Collection</a></li>
                <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#contacts">Contact us</a></li>
            </ul>
            <div class="nav-icons">
                <div class="nav-fas" id="fas1">
                    <i class="fas fa-map-marker-alt"></i>
                </div>
                <div class="nav-fas" id="fas2">
                    <i class="fas fa-envelope"></i>
                </div>
                <div class="nav-fas" id="fas3">
                    <i class="fas fa-search"></i>
                </div>
                <div class="nav-fas" id="fas4">
                    <i class="fas fa-shopping-cart"></i>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <script src="./app.js" type="module"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything is right. You just have one simple spelling mistake, you wrote `clsss` instead of `class` on three divs with class `line1, line2, line3.`

**PS:-** It looks like you are new to web development. A piece of advice for you,  make use of text editor(whatever you might be using) to detect small spelling mistakes and other linting errors. It will save you a lot of time.

Comment: Thanks so much! Thanks for the advice ill definitely make use of my editor to check for spelling mistakes